# Can I get datasets containing digital footprint of any e commerce website of users (their behavior on the website resulting in purchasing any item)?

Tags: dataset, recommendation-engine

Can I get datasets containing digital footprint of any e commerce website of users (their behavior on the website  resulting in purchasing any item)?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You are asking regarding collect some personal information without advising users. In some countries that is illegal. Please check and reformulate your question.

Comment: Take a look into https://kaggle.com/ There are plenty of datasets you can find useful like https://www.kaggle.com/carrie1/ecommerce-data